# Angular 12 load external scripts as type module

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to set Angular to load external scripts defined in the `angular.json` under `architect/build/options/scripts` as `type="module"`?

When running Angular I can see the automatically injected script tags like this:

```html
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="styles.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
<script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

The `scripts.js` has a defer attribute, but not `type="module"`. I'm trying to load a Stencil JS Web Component installed via npm into my app. The Stencil Component Script needs to be loaded as module, otherwise the other imports won't work.

Comment: Can you vote up my enhancement request here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24592#issuecomment-1401921505 ? Looking for the same thing..

Answer (score 2):

I can also confirm it's not currently possible to add a `type` attribute to the `scripts` field. Possible values are: object with *inject|lazy|bundleName|input* attributes or directly a *string*.

To use a WebComponent in Angular, I ended up adding an import statement into the `polyfills.ts` file

```
import 'node_modules/my-web-components/dist/example.js';
```

I was able to see the content imported correctly and my web component was active in my angular component html file.
[image: content added here]

Comment: Can you vote up my enhancement request here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24592#issuecomment-1401921505 ? Looking for the same thing..