# Angular 13 adds type="module" to the .js script tags in index.html

Tags: angular

I have two very similar apps, one in Angular 12 CLI and the other in Angular 13. The newer one adds type="module" to the script tags for the generated .js files, which gives MIME errors in AppEngine under chrome. If I remove 'type="module"' from dist/index.html by hand, it runs no problem. I have checked, and there is no substantive difference in tsconfig*.json nor package.json, nor angular.json, nor the source index.html. Anywhere else to look?

Comment: Not sure but maybe this can give you some hints? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56606789/angular-8-ng-build-throwing-mime-error-with-cordova

Comment: There is a thread in angular/angular-cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22159/

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Cross-origin module scripts require CORS response headers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 12 load external scripts as type module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850531/angular-12-load-external-scripts-as-type-module)

Comment: Not really. My problem is that having type="module" prevented the app from loading under AppEngine and Chrome. What I ended up doing is running a Python script to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue with Angular 14. 
Fixed it with @angular-builders/custom-webpack package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack

1. Change default builder and add index transform file

[image]

2. Replace 'type="module" with'  'crossorigin="use-credentials" defer'
   [image]

```
    module.exports = async (targetOptions, indexHtmlContent) => {
      indexHtmlContent = indexHtmlContent.replaceAll("type=\"module\"", 
      "crossorigin=\"use-credentials\" defer");
      return indexHtmlContent;
    }
```

Comment: Property indexTransform is not allowed. in angular 13

Answer (score 0):

After running into the same issue, @Roma Babiy's suggested approach resolved it  One thing to note though is that `replaceAll` might not be available during the build process:

```bash
...
✖ Index html generation failed.
indexHtmlContent.replaceAll is not a function
```

Easy to workaround it by using `replace` instead:

```js
module.exports = async (_targetOptions, indexHtmlContent) => {
  indexHtmlContent = indexHtmlContent.replace(/type="module"/g, 'crossorigin="use-credentials" defer');
  return indexHtmlContent;
}
```